# Python Threaded UDP and TCP Server?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a server that allows TCP, UDP and HTTP connections by making each process have its own thread. I already accomplished TCP and HTTP connections, and the UDP portion starts up correctly, but when I try to send a message via UDP, the system hangs. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

The UDP Class Handler:

```
class ThreadedUDPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print("{} wrote: ".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(data)
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)
```

The UDP Thread:

```
class ThreadedUDPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.UDPServer): 
        pass
```

Location in code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 8000

    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
    http_thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    print("Website serving at port", PORT)

    udpserver = ThreadedUDPServer((HOST,PORT+1), ThreadedUDPRequestHandler)
    udp_thread = threading.Thread(target=udpserver.serve_forever)
    print("UDP serving at port", PORT+1)

    tcpserver = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT-1), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=tcpserver.serve_forever)
    print("TCP serving at port", PORT-1)
    udp_thread.start()
```

Solved:
I forgot to add

```
udp_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add

```
udp_thread.start()
```

at the bottom